# динамическое управление цветом в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Нужно сделать такую штуку. Допустим есть массив, в нем один из элементов (int) отвечает за цвет рисования примитивов в `canvas`. В цикле `javascript` этот массив рисуется:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    screen.fillStyle = obj[i].col;//как это сделать? scree это контекст canvas. fillStyle принимает что-то типа '#124578' или 'rgb(12,12,12)'
    screen.fillRect(obj[i].x, obj[i].y, obj[i].width, obj[i].height);
}
```

У меня нет ни малейших идей как это реализовать, но очень надо!

---

перенесено из «ответа»:

допустим в переменной `i` некая разница между цветом отображаемых объектов.

```
screen.fillStyle = 'rgb('+i*60+', 20, '+i*45+')';
```

Comment: ну так, а как вы хотите определять - _каким именно_ цветом нужно рисовать?

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую приводить в hex-вид:

```
function getColor(index) {
   return '#' + getColorPart(42.5 * index) + getColorPart(42.5 * index) + getColor(0);
}

function getColorPart(num) {
   num = ~~num; // быстрее чем Math.floor
   var res = (0xff > num ? 0xff : 0x0 > num ? 0x00 : num).toString(16);
   return res.length === 1 ? res + '0' : res;
}

var _array = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (var i = 0, ii = _array.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i);
    ctx.fillRect(0, i*25, 25, 25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как это свойство - обычная строка с цветом - то собирать его можно как угодно, просто генерируя нужную строку, используя нужное поле.
Примеры можно увидеть в [справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

```js
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  for (var i=0;i<6;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<6;j++){
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(255-42.5*i) + ',' +
                       Math.floor(255-42.5*j) + ',0)';
      ctx.fillRect(j*25,i*25,25,25);
    }
  }
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```